# AWK: Why $* works inside bash function but not under pipe?

Tags: awk

@terdon in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106132/awk-why-does-cat-work-for-stdin-but-doesnt) answered the related question of mine, but I missed one more question in that post.

Plz refer to the following commands:

```
calc(){ awk "BEGIN{ print $* }" ;}; calc "((3+(2^3)) * 34^2 / 9)-75.89"
```

The above commands work fine with calculated result '1337'.

```
echo '((3+(2^3)) * 34^2 / 9)-75.89' | awk "BEGIN{ print $* }"
```

But the above commands don't give any result while @terdon explained well about why.

Could you advise what made the first example work with $*?

Answer (score 3):

`$*` refers to [positional parameters](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html) - those variables which are referenced by `$1` and `$2` and so on, and are provided as arguments to scripts and functions. That's the key to your question.

When you have [interactive shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell) , there's no positional parameters set by default, so `$*` is empty. You can make it work if you set those via `set "((3+(2^3)) * 34^2 / 9)-75.89"` command, which will make `$1` equal to that string.

The difference with `calc(){ awk "BEGIN{ print $* }" ;};` is that it's a function and functions can process positional parameters (theirs, not the shell's). When you call `calc "((3+(2^3)) * 34^2 / 9)-75.89"` you're calling a function with positional parameter `"((3+(2^3)) * 34^2 / 9)-75.89"`. There `$*` won't be empty:

```
$ calc(){ echo "Params: '$*'"; awk "BEGIN{ print $* }" ;}; calc "((3+(2^3)) * 34^2 / 9)-75.89"
Params: '((3+(2^3)) * 34^2 / 9)-75.89'
1337
```